# Socket on returning [Object Object] on browser console

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

This is my code currently

```
function resolveAfter1() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var scoresFromDb = db.account.find({}, { username: 1, score: 1 }).toArray(function(err, result) {
          if (err) 
              reject(err);
          else
              resolve(result);
    });
  });
}

resolveAfter1() // resolve function
    .then((result)=>{console.log(result);})
    .catch((error)=>{console.log(error);})

    async function asyncCall() {
      var result = await resolveAfter1();
      // console.log(result);
    }
```

When I do socket emit, I get [object Object]instead of the values, this is my Emit on the server

```
socket.emit('allScores', asyncCall());
```

Then this is my socket.on on the client side HTML

```
socket.on('allScores', function(data){
    console.log(data);
})
```

The answer I am getting in the chrome console is this

```
{}
```

Can anyone tell me why it's not displaying asyncCall() like this? this is what I get in the server which is perfect, but when I emit and receive it with the socket on, I don't get this?

```
[ { _id: 5a7c6552380e0a299fa752d3, username: 'test', score: 44 } ]
```

Comment: You are converting object to string with `+` and that's why you get `[object Object]`

Comment: Try doing `console.log(data)` without any string attached.

Comment: I have done that and I get this {}    followed by  __proto__: Object